# How to condense the following in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

A `Car` has multiple manufactures and I want to gather all manufacturers in a `Set`.

For example:

```
class Car {
    String name;
    List<String> manufactures;
}  

object sedan -> { ford, gm, tesla }
object sports -> { ferrari, tesla, bmw }
object suv -> { ford, bmw, toyota }
```

Now, I need to create output that contains all manufactures ( without redundancy )

I tried:

```
carList.stream().map(c -> c.getManufacturers()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This gives me a `Set` of `List`s, but I need to get rid of nesting and just create a single `Set` ( non nested ).

[EDIT] What if some objects have 'null' value for manufactures and we want to prevent NPE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
Set<String> manufactures =
    carList.stream()
           .flatMap(c -> c.getManufacturers().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you want to avoid `Car`s having `null` manufactures, add a filter:

```
Set<String> manufactures =
    carList.stream()
           .filter(c -> c.getManufacturers() != null)
           .flatMap(c -> c.getManufacturers().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: `carList.stream()
           .flatMap(c -> c.getManufacturers().stream())
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed `c.getManufacturers().stream()` will throw NullPointerException before `filter(Objects::nonNull)` is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of using method references only for conciseness would be to `map` from `Car` to `List<String>` , `filter` out the `null` lists, flatten the stream of streams and then finally collect to a Set implementation.

```
Set<String> resultSet =
          carList.stream()
                 .map(Car::getManufacturers)
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```